# XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): compilation error

Tags: php, xml, xslt, nette

please, can you help me with a problem in XML transform by XSLT in PHP?

I have this code:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents(DIR_WWW . '/xslt/test.xml'));
            $xsl = new DOMDocument();
            $xsl->load(DIR_WWW . '/xslt/test.xslt');
            $processor = new XSLTProcessor();
            $processor->importStylesheet($xsl);
            $filepath = DIR_WWW . '/xslt/output.xml';
            file_put_contents($filepath, $processor->transformToXml($xml));
            $response = new FileResponse($filepath);
            $this->presenter->sendResponse($response);
```

But I get always this error messages:
**XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): compilation error: file /srv/www/xslt/test.xslt line 3 element stylesheet**

this is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>
<dat:dataPack xmlns:dat="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/data.xsd" id="01" ico="12345678" application="Externi Aplikace" version="2.0" note="Import">
    <dat:dataPackItem id="1" version="2.0">
        <inv:invoice xmlns:inv="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/invoice.xsd" version="2.0">
            <inv:invoiceHeader>
                <inv:invoiceType>receivedInvoice</inv:invoiceType>
                <inv:number>
                    <typ:ids xmlns:typ="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/type.xsd">22F003</typ:ids>
                </inv:number>
                <inv:symVar>350</inv:symVar>
                <inv:originalDocument>350</inv:originalDocument>
                <inv:date>2022-05-01</inv:date>
                <inv:dateAccounting>2022-05-01</inv:dateAccounting>
                <inv:dateTax>2022-05-01</inv:dateTax>
            </inv:invoiceHeader>
            <inv:invoiceSummary>
                <inv:foreignCurrency>
                    <typ:currency xmlns:typ="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/type.xsd">
                        <typ:ids xmlns:typ="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/type.xsd">EUR</typ:ids>
                    </typ:currency>
                    <typ:priceSum xmlns:typ="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/type.xsd">10,6</typ:priceSum>
                </inv:foreignCurrency>
            </inv:invoiceSummary>
        </inv:invoice>
    </dat:dataPackItem>
</dat:dataPack>
```

This is my xslt file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1250"?>
<!--xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"-->
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:rsp="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/response.xsd" xmlns:rdc="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/documentresponse.xsd" xmlns:typ="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/type.xsd" xmlns:lst="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/list.xsd" xmlns:acu="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/accountingunit.xsd" xmlns:inv="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/invoice.xsd" xmlns:vch="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/voucher.xsd" xmlns:int="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/intDoc.xsd" xmlns:stk="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/stock.xsd" xmlns:ord="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/order.xsd" xmlns:ofr="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/offer.xsd" xmlns:enq="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/enquiry.xsd" xmlns:vyd="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/vydejka.xsd" xmlns:pri="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/prijemka.xsd" xmlns:pre="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/prevodka.xsd" xmlns:vyr="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/vyroba.xsd" xmlns:pro="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/prodejka.xsd" xmlns:adb="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/addressbook.xsd" xmlns:dat="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/data.xsd" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="rsp" result-prefix="xsl"/>
    <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="rdc" result-prefix="xsl"/>
    <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="typ" result-prefix="xsl"/>
    <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="lst" result-prefix="xsl"/>
    <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="acu" result-prefix="xsl"/>
    <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="inv" result-prefix="xsl"/>
    <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="vch" result-prefix="xsl"/>
    <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="int" result-prefix="xsl"/>
    <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="stk" result-prefix="xsl"/>
    <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="ord" result-prefix="xsl"/>
    <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="ofr" result-prefix="xsl"/>
    <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="enq" result-prefix="xsl"/>
    <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="vyd" result-prefix="xsl"/>
    <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="pri" result-prefix="xsl"/>
    <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="pre" result-prefix="xsl"/>
    <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="adb" result-prefix="xsl"/>
    <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="pro" result-prefix="xsl"/>
    <xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzáéíóúůýěščřžť'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÁÉÍÓÚŮÝĚŠČŘŽŤ'"/>
    <xsl:decimal-format name="cesky" decimal-separator="."/>
    <!--    Zkonvertuje Dokument z EDI prefabrikatu do S3 -->
    <xsl:template match="dat:dataPack">
        <xsl:element name="MoneyData">
            <xsl:element name="SeznamFaktPrij">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="dat:dataPackItem"/>
            </xsl:element>      
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--    Seznam faktur -->
    <xsl:template match="dat:dataPackItem">
        <xsl:element name="FaktPrij">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="inv:invoice"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <!--    Faktura -->
    <xsl:template match="inv:invoice">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="inv:invoiceHeader"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="inv:invoiceSummary"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    
    <!--    Zjištění, zda se jedná o cizí měnu ve faktuře a sumarizace faktury -->
<xsl:template match="inv:invoiceSummary">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="inv:foreignCurrency">
                <xsl:element name="Valuty">
                    <xsl:element name="Mena">
                        <xsl:element name="Kod">
                            <xsl:value-of select="inv:foreignCurrency/typ:currency/typ:ids"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="Mnozstvi">
                            <xsl:value-of select="inv:foreignCurrency/typ:amount"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="Kurs">
                            <xsl:value-of select="inv:foreignCurrency/typ:rate"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="SouhrnDPH">
                                <xsl:if test="inv:foreignCurrency/typ:priceSum">
                                    <xsl:element name="Zaklad0"><xsl:value-of select="inv:foreignCurrency/typ:priceSum"/></xsl:element>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="inv:foreignCurrency/typ:priceLow">
                                    <xsl:element name="Zaklad5"><xsl:value-of select="inv:foreignCurrency/typ:priceLow"/></xsl:element>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="inv:foreignCurrency/typ:priceLowVAT">
                                    <xsl:element name="DPH5"><xsl:value-of select="inv:foreignCurrency/typ:priceLowVAT"/></xsl:element>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="inv:foreignCurrency/typ:priceHigh">
                                    <xsl:element name="Zaklad22"><xsl:value-of select="inv:foreignCurrency/typ:priceHigh"/></xsl:element>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="inv:foreignCurrency/typ:priceHighVAT">
                                    <xsl:element name="DPH22"><xsl:value-of select="inv:foreignCurrency/typ:priceHighVAT"/></xsl:element>
                                </xsl:if>   
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:element name="SouhrnDPH">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="inv:homeCurrency/typ:priceNone">
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test="inv:homeCurrency/typ:round/typ:priceRound">
                                            <xsl:element name="Zaklad0"><xsl:value-of select="(inv:homeCurrency/typ:priceNone)+(inv:homeCurrency/typ:round/typ:priceRound)"/></xsl:element>
                                        </xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                            <xsl:element name="Zaklad0"><xsl:value-of select="inv:homeCurrency/typ:priceNone"/></xsl:element>
                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                    </xsl:choose>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:if test="inv:homeCurrency/typ:round/typ:priceRound">
                                        <xsl:element name="Zaklad0"><xsl:value-of select="inv:homeCurrency/typ:round/typ:priceRound"/></xsl:element>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:if test="inv:homeCurrency/typ:priceLow">
                                <xsl:element name="Zaklad5"><xsl:value-of select="inv:homeCurrency/typ:priceLow"/></xsl:element>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="inv:homeCurrency/typ:priceLowVAT">
                                <xsl:element name="DPH5"><xsl:value-of select="inv:homeCurrency/typ:priceLowVAT"/></xsl:element>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="inv:homeCurrency/typ:priceHigh">
                                <xsl:element name="Zaklad22"><xsl:value-of select="inv:homeCurrency/typ:priceHigh"/></xsl:element>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="inv:homeCurrency/typ:priceHighVAT">
                                <xsl:element name="DPH22"><xsl:value-of select="inv:homeCurrency/typ:priceHighVAT"/></xsl:element>
                            </xsl:if>
            </xsl:element>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
    
    
    <!-- informace o faktuře -->
    <xsl:template match="inv:invoiceHeader">
        <xsl:element name="Doklad">
            <xsl:value-of select="inv:number/typ:numberRequested"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="PrijatDokl">
            <xsl:value-of select="inv:number/typ:numberRequested"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="EvCisDokl">
            <xsl:value-of select="inv:number/typ:numberRequested"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <!-- Zjištění dobropisu -->
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="inv:invoiceType='issuedCreditNotice'">
                <xsl:element name="Dobropis">1</xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="DobrDUZP">
                    <xsl:value-of select="inv:dateTax"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="Doruceno">
                    <xsl:value-of select="inv:dateTax"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="inv:invoiceType='issuedCorrectiveTax'">
                <xsl:element name="Dobropis">1</xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="DobrDUZP">
                    <xsl:value-of select="inv:dateTax"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="Doruceno">
                    <xsl:value-of select="inv:dateTax"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="inv:invoiceType='issuedInvoice'">
                <xsl:element name="Dobropis">0</xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:element name="Dobropis">0</xsl:element>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:element name="Popis">
            <xsl:value-of select="inv:text"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="TextPredFa">
            <xsl:value-of select="inv:text"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <!-- rozlišení malých a velkých písmen -->
        <xsl:element name="Cinnost">
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(inv:activity/typ:ids, $smallcase, $uppercase)"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="Zakazka">
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(inv:contract/typ:ids, $smallcase, $uppercase)"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="Stredisko">
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(inv:centre/typ:ids, $smallcase, $uppercase)"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="Vystaveno">
            <xsl:value-of select="inv:date"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="DatUcPr">
            <xsl:value-of select="inv:dateTax"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="PlnenoDPH">
            <xsl:value-of select="inv:dateTax"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="Splatno">
            <xsl:value-of select="inv:dateDue"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="DatSkPoh">
            <xsl:value-of select="inv:dateTax"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="VarSymbol">
            <xsl:value-of select="inv:symVar"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="ParSymbol">
            <xsl:value-of select="inv:symVar"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="KonstSym">
            <xsl:value-of select="inv:symConst"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="Uhrada">
            <xsl:value-of select="inv:paymentType/typ:ids"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <!-- <xsl:element name="TextPredFa">            <xsl:value-of select="inv:dateTax"/>             </xsl:element>    -->
        <xsl:element name="CObjednavk">
            <xsl:value-of select="inv:numberOrder"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <!-- Informace o dodavateli -->
        <xsl:element name="DodOdb">
            <xsl:element name="Tel">
                <xsl:element name="Cislo">
                    <xsl:value-of select="inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:phone"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="EMail">
                <xsl:value-of select="inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:email"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="ICO">                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(replace(inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:ico,'[a-zA-Z]',''))"/>        </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="DIC">
                <xsl:value-of select="inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:dic"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <!-- sloučení Názvu firmy a Jména kontaktní osoby -->
            <xsl:if test="string-length(inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:company) &gt; 0">
                <xsl:if test="string-length(inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:name) &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:element name="FaktNazev">
                        <xsl:value-of select="inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:company"/> * <xsl:value-of select="inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:name"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="ObchNazev">
                        <xsl:value-of select="inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:company"/> * <xsl:value-of select="inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:name"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="string-length(inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:company) &gt; 0">
                <xsl:if test="string-length(inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:name) = 0">
                    <xsl:element name="FaktNazev">
                        <xsl:value-of select="inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:company"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="ObchNazev">
                        <xsl:value-of select="inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:company"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="string-length(inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:company) = 0">
                <xsl:if test="string-length(inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:name) &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:element name="FaktNazev">
                        <xsl:value-of select="inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:name"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="ObchNazev">
                        <xsl:value-of select="inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:name"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:element name="ObchAdresa">
                <xsl:element name="Ulice">
                    <xsl:value-of select="inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:street"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="Misto">
                    <xsl:value-of select="inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:city"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="PSC">
                    <xsl:value-of select="inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:zip"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="FaktAdresa">
                <xsl:element name="Ulice">
                    <xsl:value-of select="inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:street"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="Misto">
                    <xsl:value-of select="inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:city"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="PSC">
                    <xsl:value-of select="inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:zip"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
        <!-- Informace o konečném příjemci -->
        <xsl:element name="KonecPrij">
            <!-- sloučení Názvu firmy a Jména kontaktní osoby -->
            <xsl:if test="string-length(inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:company) &gt; 0">
                <xsl:if test="string-length(inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:name) &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:element name="Nazev">
                        <xsl:value-of select="inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:company"/> * <xsl:value-of select="inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:name"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="string-length(inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:company) &gt; 0">
                <xsl:if test="string-length(inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:name) = 0">
                    <xsl:element name="Nazev">
                        <xsl:value-of select="inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:company"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="string-length(inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:company) = 0">
                <xsl:if test="string-length(inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:name) &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:element name="Nazev">
                        <xsl:value-of select="inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:name"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:element name="Adresa">
                <xsl:element name="Misto">
                    <xsl:value-of select="inv:partnerIdentity/typ:shipToAddress/typ:city"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="Ulice">
                    <xsl:value-of select="inv:partnerIdentity/typ:shipToAddress/typ:street"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="PSC">
                    <xsl:value-of select="inv:partnerIdentity/typ:shipToAddress/typ:zip"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What can I doing with this message?

---

@MartinHonnen
Ok, thank you.
I installed docker image by using this code of dockerfile:

```
FROM wodby/php:8.1-dev

USER root

RUN apk add --no-cache curl unzip \
    && curl -o libsaxon.zip https://www.saxonica.com/download/libsaxon-HEC-linux-v12.1.zip \
    && unzip libsaxon.zip -d /usr/local/lib \
    && rm -f libsaxon.zip \
    && echo "extension=saxon.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/saxon.ini

USER wodby
```

I use nette framework. Can you help me, how can I use saxonProcessor in my framework? I have this config.neon

```
    parameters:
        saxonSoPath: '/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/saxon.ini'
     # lib .so
    saxon:
        type: Saxon\SaxonProcessor
        factory: Saxon\SaxonProcessor::__construct
        arguments: [%saxonSoPath%]
```

But this code it's not working.
If I create new instance in php file, I get this error:
Class or interface 'Saxon\SaxonProcessor' not found.

Comment: Which XSLT engine are you using? You transform works fine with a XSLT 3.0 engine (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyyho8F), but fails with an XSLT 1.0 engine as you are using the translate funciton (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyyho8F/1).

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Comment: IMHO, it is `replace()` function that is tripping you.

Comment: If you really want to use XSLT 2 or 3 with PHP you need to consider SaxonC https://www.saxonica.com/download/c.xml, https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/documentation12/index.html, https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/documentation12/index.html#!api/saxon_c_php_api

Comment: PHPs ext/xslt supports XSLT 1 only. However it allows for EXSLT and callbacks into PHP. It is possible to emulate a lot of the XSLT 2/3 functions.

Answer (score 0):

Before going to extremes, try changing line 212 of your stylesheet from:

```
        <xsl:element name="ICO">                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(replace(inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:ico,'[a-zA-Z]',''))"/>        </xsl:element>
```

to:

```
        <xsl:element name="ICO">                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(translate(inv:partnerIdentity/typ:address/typ:ico, concat($smallcase, $uppercase),''))"/>        </xsl:element>
```

---

CAVEAT: Untested, may produce unintended result (the purpose of the original code is not clear).

Note that your stylesheet is written very poorly and could use a ground-up rewrite.